# pre-trained BERT model learning wrong way

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I have trained my pre-trained BERT model from the Hugging Face library on the `Jigsaw Toxic Comment Classification dataset` to detect hateful comments. However, when I try to do infer with the positive sentences, it is giving me wrong results.

For example, if I provide the sentence: `You are a nice person`, sometimes it predicts as a toxic or insult but for the negative sentences, it is giving the right result.

```py
#####################  Inference part #########
test_comment = "You are a nice person"

encoding = tokenizer.encode_plus(   
test_comment,   
  add_special_tokens=True,   
  max_length=512,    
  return_token_type_ids=False,   
  padding="max_length",      
  return_attention_mask=True,   
  return_tensors='pt',     
)

_, test_prediction = trained_model(encoding["input_ids"], encoding["attention_mask"])
test_prediction = test_prediction.flatten().numpy()

for label, prediction in zip(LABEL_COLUMNS, test_prediction):
  print(f"{label}: {prediction}")
```

```
Result: 
toxic: 0.289602130651474 
severe_toxic: 0.012312621809542179 
obscene: 0.26335516571998596 
threat: 0.0017053773626685143 
insult: 0.54698246717453 
identity_hate: 0.0013856851728633046
```

Here are my training details:

```
BERT model: bert-base-uncased 
epochs: 4 
batch-size: 16 
Learning rate: 2e-5 
Loss function: BCE loss
```

Since the dataset is imbalanced, I have done undersampling for the majority class. I also tested with augmenting the dataset, but it didn't help much.

Is there any reason, why this model is associating the positive sentences with toxicity?
[image: Classification report]

Comment: How big is your training data? Did you try and overfit the model on a singular data example, and does it return the correct classification for a this sample? *How* imbalanced is your data?

Comment: Can you provide the classification report or the confusion matrix for your test data?

Comment: @dennlinger, I took ~1,06,000 for training and 33,367 for the validation.  I had augmented the dataset to have more toxic comments. For the training, I took 54,000 toxic comments and 52,000 non-toxic comments.